# Why my RegularExpressionValidator allows do not enter any text?

Tags: asp.net, regex

Why this code allows user do not enter any text? AFAIK `+` means `One or more` .

```
<asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="9" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server"
   ControlToValidate="myTextBox"
   ValidationExpression="\d+"
   ErrorMessage="Error!" />
```

I want user was able to enter only 9 digits. And this field is required. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex validators only work when text is entered by default. I would recommend putting in a separate RequiredFieldValidator so you can have a more helpful error message.

Now your ValidationExpression should be `\d{9}`.

Comment: Why don't you recommend using that property? What is it's name?

Comment: Woops my fault. I was mistaken. I'll edit my response. I still wouldn't recommend it if it exists because the error message is less useful. Error in my experience work better when they are very clear and specific.

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx):

> **Note**:  Validation succeeds if the
>   input control is empty. If a value is
>   required for the associated input
>   control, use a RequiredFieldValidator
>   control in addition to the
>   RegularExpressionValidator control.

Answer (score 1):

Most asp.net validators do not fire when there is no text. This basically introduces the need for an extra `RequiredFieldValidator`, which you should add:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1"
                ControlToValidate="myTextBox"
                Display="Static"
                ErrorMessage="Required field"
                runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the rest of the code from the page, this bit looks good but the problem might lie within the form you are using,  do you have runat="server" in your form declaration?

Try adding this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv" Display="None" runat="server" ControlToValidate="myTextBox" ErrorMessage="name is required!"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```